# conditionPanel does not take into account the conditions

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I have two radio buttons A and B. When button A is checked, two widgets are displayed. When we check button B, the widgets of button A are deleted and we display the widgets of button B, same thing if we check button A again.
To achieve this I used the function *conditionalPanel()* but the problem is that all are displayed at the same time. There are button A and button B elements

```
mod_models_ui <- function(id){ns <- NS(id); tagList(
    radioButtons(ns("radioBtn"), "", c("A" = "idA", "B" = "idB"), selected = "idA"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = paste0("input.", ns("radioBtn"), " == 'idA'"),
      h3("A"), textInput("text1", "Widget 1"), textInput("text2", "Widget 2")),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = paste0("input.", ns("radioBtn"), " == 'idB'"),
      h3("B"),textInput("text3", "Widget 3"),textInput("text4", "Widget 4")))
}

mod_models_server <- function(id){moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){ns <- session$ns
    observe({print(input$radioBtn) })}
```

app_ui.R

```
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    ...
    mod_models_ui("radioBtn"))}
```

app_server.R

```
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_models_server("radioBtn")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that similar to accessing elements in R via `$` you can access object properties in JS using dot notation (`.`) only when they are valid variable names, which `radioBtn-radioBtn` is not, i.e. you have to use bracket notation (`[]`), e.g. `condition = paste0("input['", ns("radioBtn"), "'] === 'idA'")`. However, you can achieve your result more easily by using the `ns=` argument of `conditionalPanel`:

```r
mod_models_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    radioButtons(ns("radioBtn"), "", c("A" = "idA", "B" = "idB"), selected = "idA"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.radioBtn === 'idA'",
      h3("A"),
      textInput("text1", "Widget 1"),
      textInput("text2", "Widget 2"),
      ns = ns
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.radioBtn === 'idB'",
      h3("B"),
      textInput("text3", "Widget 3"), textInput("text4", "Widget 4"),
      ns = ns
    )
  )
}

mod_models_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    observe({
      print(input$radioBtn)
    })
  })
}

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_models_ui("radioBtn")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_models_server("radioBtn")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8788
#> [1] "idA"
```

[image]